# $('element').show(); vs $('element').css('visibility', 'visible'): which is better to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function

There are two ways for showing/hiding an element. First is `$('element').show()`, where `show()` is a function in Jquery, and `$('element').css('visibility', 'visible')` where `css()` comes from Jquery too. Which is faster, and what to use? I think that the first is faster.

Comment: Both `$.fn.css` and `$.fn.show` come from jQuery. Not sure what “connect to jQuery” means. `show()` sets `display`, not `visibility`. If you don’t care about the difference, use `show()` and `hide()` because they’re shorter and easier to read.

Comment: @Ry-   Ok, I edited.

Comment: @Ry- And what about speed?

Comment: I think `.show()` would be faster as it is specific for display property, whereas `.css()` is a general function for all properties

Comment: You've already spent more time reading this comment than the time spent on the difference between the two (which ever *is* faster) would have been for the entire life-cycle of your project.  There's probably other places you can improve speed (eg chaining, storing lookups) - tl;dr don't worry about it, it's too small to worry about.

Comment: @freedomn-m When there is slow internet, it is very important, as it can be one second, or two seconds.

Comment: Bandwidth is a completely separate concern from clientside performance -- once jQuery itself has downloaded and the client script is running, network conditions are irrelevant (unless you start making ajax or other network calls).

Comment: @Nick slow internet has no impact.  Both are run on the client.  If you have such a slow PC/device that the difference of these two makes a difference, then you have much bigger problems.   Again, if it's making a difference, it would be obvious in testing which to use and likely some other code causing the difference (eg not caching jquery lookups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `.show()` is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "block" ), except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Setting `.css('visibility', 'visible')` will only show the element if it was previously hidden using `visibility: hidden`.  `show()` changes the `display` property instead.   The key difference between the two methods is their layout behavior (`visibility:hidden` elements still take up space in the layout, `display:none` elements do not).

As for speed / performance:  [when in doubt, run a benchmark](https://jsfiddle.net/0xm5z963/).  Contrary to your guess, jQuery visibility is significantly faster than show/hide.   In vanilla JS this difference evaporates, at least for simple document layouts; both methods are roughly the same speed (and both are *much* faster than either jQuery method).  My results on the linked benchmark:

- jQuery show/hide x 20,913 ops/sec ±2.49% (75 runs sampled)
- jQuery visibility x 121,719 ops/sec ±1.46% (81 runs sampled)
- vanilla show/hide x 453,574 ops/sec ±2.51% (85 runs sampled)
- vanilla visibility x 450,610 ops/sec ±1.98% (89 runs sampled)

It's difficult to imagine any plausible situation in which this difference in performance would be significant; the layout difference would generally be the real deciding factor here... but if your app needs to show and hide tens of thousands of elements per second, you should run a benchmark against your actual code and find out if there are specific details about your implementation that would make one or the other preferable.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments both `.css()` and `.show()` are part of jQuery, the main difference between the two is that the first assign a specific value to the css `visibility` property and the other restores the initial `display` value of the element (block or inline block for example)

Answer (score 0):

**In both visibility and hide/show, the style will added as inline**
**Visibility**
`.css('visibility', 'visible');`, only the visibility will be hidden. But display will not be none.

**Hide/show**
It is very simple and equivalent to `.css("display", "block")`;

**Which one is faster?**
I think, commonly it is not used for that kind of feature, but it is used for interactions, functionalities in the events, etc...